# WPF PropertyDependency Binding To Different Types

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

type here

userControl code

```
        public double Version
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(VersionProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(VersionProperty, value);
                SetValue(Version_StringProperty, $"Ver{value:0.00}");
            }
        }

        public string Version_String
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(Version_StringProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(Version_StringProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty VersionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Version", typeof(double), typeof(MachineVersionObject));
        
        public static readonly DependencyProperty Version_StringProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Version_String", typeof(string), typeof(MachineVersionObject));
```

XAML

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Version_String, ElementName=maachineVersion, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="15" Foreground="#F1F1F1" FontWeight="Bold"
                               Margin="2 3 2 0" />
```

How do i bind a double type to a dependency property string or pass the Version property to the Version_string property?

I tried binding the Version Property directly to the textblock and it displayed the values
"1.36" "2" "2.5"

But i would like to add a "Ver" in front and make the values displayed all 2 decimal places.

Comment: Are you saying that the XAML binding (for the `TextBlock`) you showed does not work?

Comment: I would like to know how to update the Version_String Property when the Version Property is set. So i can bind Version_String to the TextBlock's Text.

Comment: It would be better to use [System.Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version) instead of double for handling version information.

Comment: Sry but this is not about the Application Version but the Version of the object used.

Comment: You should learn StringFormat https://wpf-tutorial.com/en/40/data-binding/the-stringformat-property/

Comment: D'oh! I thought the problem was with the wiring. Just a simple formatting issue. Oh well.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a rough sketch that (I think) does what you want. The magic is in the setter/getter method of the bound properties, which utilize the `Update` method in `INotifier` to update each other and the GUI and vice versa.

I used 2 text boxes (first changes the version number) because it simpler to make a quick GUI that way, but in principle I think this is what you are looking for:

[image]

.NET 6, Visual Studio WPF Application template:

`MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:ViewModel}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="75" Width="100">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding VersionNumber}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding VersionString}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

`MainWindow.xaml.cs` (note, `ViewModel` class should be its own file):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{

    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged = null;

        protected void Update<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return;

            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler? handler = PropertyChanged;
            handler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        private string _versionString = "Ver1";
        private string _versionNumber = "1";
        private int _version = 1;
        public string VersionString
        {
            get => _versionString;
            set { Update(ref _versionString, value); }
        }

        public string VersionNumber
        {
            get => _versionNumber;
            set
            {
                _versionNumber = value;
                _version = int.Parse(_versionNumber);
                VersionString = $"Ver{_version}";
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Final detail, I modified `App.xaml` and `App.xaml.cs` in order to wire the data context to the gui properly

xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1">
    <Application.Resources>
         
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App

    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            var viewModel = new ViewModel();
            var mainWindow = new MainWindow { DataContext = viewModel };
            mainWindow.Show();
        }
    }
}
```